# Internal Format Error using Office.context.mailbox.item.to.getasync after ~10minutes

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins, office365-apps

Actually we're creating an Add-In for Outlook. 
This Add-in is using the Office.context.mailbox.item.to API.

We have noticed that, when we create a function with an interval that is calling the getAysnc from mailbox.item.to (each 500ms), after ~10 minutes, we get an Internal Format Error.

> There was an internal format error  (9002)

Here our code:

```
setInterval(function () {
                self.updateRecipients();
            }, self.lookupRate);

self.updateRecipients = function () {
        var item = Office.context.mailbox.item;

        item.to.getAsync(function (asyncResult) {
            self.setRecipients(0, asyncResult);
        });  };


self.setRecipients = function (index, asyncResult) {

    if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
        //#INTERNERR
        console.log("error: " + asyncResult.error.message);
    }};
```

Is it possible, any session is killed after 10 minutes, or what can be the reason of this kind of error.

We are working on Outlook.com with Google Chrome on Windows 10.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Best Regards

Comment: We are unable to repro the error with code snippet which you provided. We tried calling this API in interval for ~15 min and we didn't get any error. There is similar post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50473233/office365-addfileattachmentasync-error-when-doing-multiple-requests where we have explained how to invoke multiple async calls. Please check if it helps.

Comment: After some more analysis and researches we could easily reproduce the error. It's due to massif calls on getAsync (Office.context.mailbox.item.to.getAsync). Sometimes, we do a new call before we recieved the response of the older call. We fixed this issue using recursive calls only when we've recieved the getAsync result:   self.updateRecipientsCC = function () {
        var item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
        item.cc.getAsync(function (asyncResult) {
            self.setRecipients(1, asyncResult);
            self.delay(0.5);
            self.updateRecipientsCC();
        }); };

Comment: So we take it this issue is fixed?